# Linq query with OrderBy word count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have this bit of code,

```
 public static List<string> GetSentencesFromWords(List<string> words, string fileContents)
{
    return fileContents.Split('.')
        .Where(s => words.Any(w => s.IndexOf(w) != -1))
        .Select(s => s.TrimStart(' ') + ".")
        .ToList();
}
```

It works brilliantly, another user helped me with it in another question, but I thought my new question related to it warranted a new post. I need the returned word list to be ordered by the number of matches in each sentence. I have tried to do it a few ways but I am not very experienced with Linq and everything I have tried just seems to sort by sentence length rather than word count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and it should work for you?

```
return fileContents.Split('.')
    .Where(s => words.Any(w => s.IndexOf(w) != -1))
    .Select(s => s.TrimStart(' ') + ".")
    .OrderByDescending(s => words.Count(w => s.IndexOf(w) != -1))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What about if a word is repeated in a sentence?

Comment: @Hexxagonal Good point, but I think he's just looking for actually how many matches there is on ANY word, not multiple different words. He only says "I need the returned word list to be ordered by the number of matches in each sentence". I assumed that was regardless of whether there was more than one of the same word, it's still a match?

Comment: Yeah, reading that again... you might be right.  It's not entirely clear what he wants.

Comment: She wants a count, not really concerned with the number of times, doubles should be very rare. I cant tell the difference between this one and the other answer, which would be better?

Comment: @SpectralEdge to be honest, I'd say mine was better (not blowing my own trumpet) because I think Regexs are not well suited here. It can be done by simply using the string class, no need to use a Regex. Plus, I could be wrong, but you may get some inconsistent results with regexs if some of your words had certain characters in ($, @, [ ) etc.

Comment: As far as we consider words we assume that thay do not contain special characters, so my solution is correct in this way. But to be honest I think that you are right about that Regex seems redundant here. Just one more option.

Comment: @StuffHappens yeah there's definitely nothing wrong with yours for sure I just thought as he's reading in sentences, you can never be too sure what characters could lurk in there! I +1ed your answer :)

Comment: I need to get matches of whole words only like right now searching for lips grabs sentences with Philips, I tried to grab them only if there was a space before and after the word, but that didn't work for the beginning or end of a sentence. Do you have an idea how to fix?

Comment: You'll need to change the s.IndexOf(w) != -1 checks just to be s == w to do a direct comparison.

Comment: Oh actually, if s is still the sentence you'll need to change s.IndexOf(w) != -1 to s.Split(' ').Any(sw => sw == w) to compare each actual word in the sentence.

Comment: Wont that only work on the words that are in the center of a sentence, not the beginning and the end? Like if a word is followed by a period, it won't find it, nor will it find the ones at the beginning of a paragraph since they are not preceded by a space.

Comment: No because if you had the sentence "The lazy dog jumped over a fence", then the search word was "The", it would still find it because the split is made on the spaces, so s[0] would be "The" and therefore it would match :). I'm not sure what a period is? Is that an American term? You could try trimming out any punctuation if you had issues with that too.

Comment: Period is hmm end of sentence, terminator? I forget what others call it. "." is a period. And I need the period otherwise how will I know if it is a sentence?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean trimming, I meant splitting (like we split at the space for the words).

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
return fileContents.Split('.')
   .Where(s => words.Any(w => s.Contains(w) != -1))
   .Select(s => s.TrimStart(' ') + ".")
   .OrderByDescending(s => words.Sum(w => Regex.Matches(s, w).Count))
   .ToList();
```

don't forget to include
`using System.Text.RegularExpressions`